# Other alternative for "does that make sense"?

Tags: slang

What are other alternatives for "Does that make sense"? I personally think this phrase is natural, not rude nor respectful.

Are any other alternatives for when you try to sound more serious/angry (or when on the other hand really diplomatic or polite.)

Any I'm not looking for something literal similar "Do you understand?" or the other neutral ones which are listed here  https://www.allearsenglish.com/check-someone-understands-youve-said-english/

Comment: "does it make sense?" is a well-known phrase. And "make the scene". But "does it make scene" is not a common English idiom, nor is it understandable based on the usual meanings of the words employed. Where did you read this phrase and what do you think it means?

Comment: There's still a typo in the title. Now it says "scese". Anyway, you should write a sentence showing how this word/expression would be used. Leave a gap/blank where the expression (or idiom) goes.

Answer (score 0):

In English (and, I expect, most other languages as well), the tone you use when speaking can have as much to do with the "harshness" of the word or phrase as the words themselves do. Almost any sentence can be harsh or polite depending on your tone.

That said, a sentence that would be a little harsher would be "Do you understand?", especially if you said it very forcefully.

If you wanted to be more informal, a simple "Get it?" will probably work (for example, if you just told a joke and wanted to ask if the person you told it to understood the joke).

Comment: Yes, the question is not how to utter those to sounds harsh or polite. It's obviouse

Comment: My point is, in this case, there isn't really a sentence that is by nature harsh or polite, at least not that I can think of. But you can use almost any of the above sentences, or almost any of the sentences on the website that you linked to in your question, to sound either harsh or polite.

Comment: Yes, Thaddaeus, It's common sense. In writing (chat, email, etc.) it's just not possible.

Comment: I understand that. But there's a "speaking" tag on the question, so I thought that that was all you needed. ;-)